# Как отправить сообщение участнику stackoverflow?

Tags: поддержка

У меня возник уточняющий вопрос к участнику https://ru.stackoverflow.com/
и я хотел задать его не публично; в его профиле нет ссылок на публичные профили, а контактные данные скрыты или отсутствуют.

Comment: @Etki понятно, просто те вопросы, которые я задаю, закрывают...

Comment: @JavaDeveloper вы можете поговорить с ним в чате.

Comment: @Suvitruf спасибо, нашел чат http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms, буду бороться за Права На Общение (Присуждается За: 100 Баллов Репутации :)

Comment: так это чтобы создавать 100, чтобы заходить вроде репутация не важна

Comment: кроме того, можете упомянуть его с помощью `@имя` в комментариях к его ответу, например, и ему придет уведомление об этом. И возможно чат создаст уже он сам :)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat - там 20 надо, а не 100. 1-2 хороших ответа и готово.

Comment: @JavaDeveloper по поводу закрытия ваших вопросов - дело в том, что вы не задаете вопросы. вы добавляете новые *ответы* к уже существующим вопросам. Если есть новая проблема - стоит просто оформить ее как отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Скрытых контактных данных в профиле пользователя нет. Всё что заполнил сам участник, показывается даже незарегистрированному посетителю. Если там контактные данные не указаны, то вы можете оставить комментарий под каким-нибудь вопросом или ответом участника с предложением написать вам и вашей почтой или другим контактом.